# My english page does not show

Tags: plugins

My english page does not show instead I get the message that the page cannot be found I can see the content  but It is not published. I do not know if it makes sense. This is the website https://mathimatahispanikon.com/
Can you please hlep?
Thank you
Timi

Comment: you appear to have a multi-language system or some kind of structure set up, but there's no information about how you did this in your question, can you edit your question to include these details as well as anything else that might be useful? Your question need to contain _everything_ needed to answer the question, and any back and forth to get more information greatly reduces the chances and quality of the answers you get, if you get any at all